# How to print a single string cell from a column in a .csv Python data frame?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I want to be able to print out the name of the continent that has the most capital cities from a CSV data frame. Note: I'm doing this in JupyterLab.

This is what the question asks: Print out the continent with the most capitals.

Here is what I did:

```
import csv
with open(`C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python/Scripts/caps.csv', "r") as continent:
   reader = csv.reader(continent, delimiter='\t')
   for lines in reader:
       print(lines[5])
```

However, the above code prints every continent in column 5. How would you print out just one continent e.g. "Africa" from the column?

Image of the csv file:
[image]

Comment: First, you need to figure out how to count the capitals for each continent. Have you tried to do that?

Comment: Also, you'll get more help if you post a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use as well the [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) package, which is very useful to load and manage csv files. Then with following code you can get all entries from Africa.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python/Scripts/caps.csv")
dfAfrica = df[df[df.columns[5]]=="Africa"]
```

Then the variable `dfAfrica` would be the `DataFrame` you can print and see the data you were willing to filter.

Comment: If so please consider to upvote and/or mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
   if lines[5]=='Africa':
       print(lines[5])
```

But this seems kind of redundant as it will print "Africa" for every line that contains "Africa" in column 5. Is this *really* what you need to do?

Comment: What I did was basically searched the Internet for the continent containing the most capital cities and it turned out to be Africa. Then I assumed, once you've found out which continent has the most capitals then just simply print out the continent name from the cell.